# How to create new class to benefit descendants without domino effect of new classes

Tags: c++, inheritance, descendant

I have inherited a C++ system that was designed to be very modular.  So one class derives from another, derives from another, etc.

For example, class C inherits from class B which inherits from class A

> C <- B <- A

I was asked NOT to change the original classes.  I would now like to make a new class (eg: A2) which derives from A and improves upon A.  In order for this system to benefit from my A2, do I have to derive from B to make a new B2 which uses A2?  And then derive from C to make a new C2 which uses B2?

Is it possible to derive new classes which allow all other descendant classes to immediately benefit?  It appears to me that creating A2 will create a domino effect of having to create new classes.  A lot of work when OO is supposed to avoid this kind of thing.

I suspect I'm missing some concept

Comment: You haven't provided enough information.  The only way class `B` will "benefit" (whatever that means) from your defining another class `A2` that inherits from `A` is if `B` (and possibly `A`) includes some specific code that will behave differently if there is a new class `A2`.    Without information about what your "C++ system" does, and what classes `A` and `B` do, it is impossible for anyone to give a sensible answer to your question.

Comment: OO is *not* supposed to make it so you don't have to change classes that were already written. The OO way to improve a class is to improve that class, not to make a new class that inherits from it.

Comment: To benefit descendants transparently, can you create a class named A, which derives from A ?